# How do i create multiple mysql table using php?

Tags: php, mysql

so this is my code and it only add the data to a table called 'registration' i want it to create its own table using $firstName

```
<?php
$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$number = $_POST['number'];

// Database connection
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','test');
if($conn->connect_error){
    echo "$conn->connect_error";
    die("Connection Failed : ". $conn->connect_error);
} else {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("insert into registration(firstName, lastName, gender, email, password, number) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sssssi", $firstName, $lastName, $gender, $email, $password, $number);
    $execval = $stmt->execute();
    echo $execval;
    echo "Registration successfully...";
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
}
```

?>

Comment: **it only adds the data to a table called 'registration'** - is the normal way of db data insertion operation. What is the purpose to create a separate table for each new data record ?

Comment: Why would you want to create a new table for each name? This defeats the purpose of MySQL database